# File sharing between devices using network

Tags: android, networking

I want to write a simple app to communicate between devices. I mean send very small files (small images, text or audio files) from one device to another but not using bluetooth or nfc but by internet. How can I do this and would this be hard to do for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your experience level it can get pretty hard. I would suggest you use
 [GCM Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
It's a push notification system that can deliver messages to anyone of the devices running your app. Your app on the device can process the message being received. The message size is 4096 bytes only so for sending larger files you can use:
[Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/)
This is a RPC api endpoint and it can store your files in between waiting for recipient to download the file

Here's a grate tutorial on [Google Cloud Endpoints](http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to find how to do it with google cloud messaging. My experience is not big but maybe I'll manage to do something.

Comment: @fgsh: Did you find some solution or tutorial ? If yes please share I am looking for similar thing